# Setting initial state of PrintPreviewDialog controls

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm working with PrintPreviewDialog and want to tweak its initial presentation from the default. So far, I've done this:

```
            PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            dlg.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            dlg.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.0;
```

...which gives me the presentation I want, but when the dialog is opened, the zoom control has the "Auto" choice selected, not 100% as would correspond to the zoom value of 1.0. How can I get at the zoom control to show 100% as the currently selected zoom setting so as not to confuse the user?

BTW, this is VS 2010 .NET 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe setting `AutoZoom = false` will help:

```
dlg.PrintPreviewControl.AutoZoom = false;
```

The `PrintPreviewControl` should reflect the value of `AutoZoom` and `Zoom` but it doesn't. That's a strange thing in its design. However after a search on this control, I've found that we can access to the `ToolStrip` of the `PrintPreviewDialog`. This dialog has 2 child controls by default. The first is the `PrintPreviewControl` which is exposed via the property `PrintPreviewControl`, the second is the `ToolStrip`. By looping through the `Items`, you can find the exact `ToolStripSplitButton` (the Zoom button) and by looping through the `DropDownItems` of that splitbutton, we can find the exact `100%` toolstripdropdownitem and call `PerformClick` to check it. However by default, I think we know the index of the item beforehand and the following code would work:

```
ToolStripSplitButton zoomButton = ((ToolStrip)dlg.Controls[1]).Items[1] as ToolStripSplitButton;
zoomButton.DropDownItems[4].PerformClick();//Check the 100% item in the zoom list
```

Comment: Tried it, had no apparent effect.

Comment: @rObjects your code with `.Zoom=1.0` should also be used. Is there still the choice `Auto`?

Comment: I left the Zoom = 1.0 in when I added the AutoZoom, = false did not affect the zoom control initial setting - remained on the "Auto" selection.

Comment: @rObjects OK, I updated the answer, it's a little tricky but it works and that's the only solution (I'm 99% sure).

Comment: That's doing it... although I think it could use a bit of "bulletproofing", but I can easily figure that out from what you've provided.

Comment: @rObjects you can try looping through all the items and print out to see their names... The point is **we have access to the control `ToolStrip` through the `Controls` property of `PrintPreviewDialog`**. That's all enough for us to access any other child items on that `ToolStrip`.

Comment: Did that, thanks... you gave me exactly what I needed to get there.

Answer (score 1):

```
dlg.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom=100/100f;

dlg.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom=2; // 200% Zoom
```

Comment: It is better to add some description with your answer. Then the other users also can understand the answer.